# Updating to Windows 7 SP1

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, boot-camp, service-pack

I'm running Windows 7 ultimate on a Mac, through Bootcamp (MacBook 2009, 4gb, 2.2ghz), and I'm trying to update to Windows 7 SP1 (or directly to Windows 10 if there's a way) but when trying to install SP1 through Windows update agent I'm getting error code 8e5e0408, or Windows update agent keeps searching for updates forever. When trying to install it via an .exe downloaded from the Windows software catalog I'm getting error 0x8e5e0408 (this happens after the installer creates a restore point, and while it's installing KB976902, the installer is almost finished installing SP1, about 80% when this error happens).

Any thoughts on how I could update to SP1/Windows 10, and fix these errors? Thanks!

P.S.
I have already tried doing a clean boot (all unnecessary services turned off), and tried installing the updates while is safe mode

Comment: Have you tired the basics yet, like using MS' [Windows Update Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/971058), or [resetting your Windows update components](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/971058)?  If so, what were the results?

Comment: [Read this  page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2505743)

Comment: @Moab that walkthrough didnt help, still getting the same errors.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes, I ran the 'fix it' app, and it did not do anything, I'll try the terminal fix